# Pig_Latin Captitalization

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question**: Pig Latin is a code that:-

1. Adds "ay" to every word.
2. If the word starts with a consonant, move the first letter to the end.
3. Final word should have the first letter as capital.

**My Approach**:  I have gotten the first part figured out, but the code is very buggy when the first letter is capitalized, it will not do it with the same format. What is supposed to happen is that the new first letter will get capitalized, but that is not what happened(ex: Test --> Esttay)

I have tried nesting the conditional of word.capitalize() using if statement, however, it didn't work out, and confused it with the else statement. I have also tried creating a separate list, and all the times the computer got it confused.

Here's my code:

```
sentence = input ("Type in your sentence here ")

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] 

for word in sentence.split():
    first_letter = word [0]

    if first_letter in consonants :           
        pig = word [1:] + first_letter + "ay"
    else :
        pig = word + "ay"
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.islower() == "false":
            print (pig.iscapitalize())
        else :
            print (pig)
```

The expected result is that the code can automatically captitalize the right place (Test --> Esttay), however, for consonants, it will treat it as vowel (Test --> Testay).

Thank you for helping me

Comment: `if word.islower() == "false":` Did you mean `== False`? Also, what's with that second loop?

Comment: I would suggest to start by fixing your indentation in the question, it looks off

Comment: Just parse it as a lowercase word using word.lower()

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be the `word.islower() == "false"`, which will never be true. Instead, check `word.islower() == False`, or rather `not word.islower()`, or `word.istitle()`. Also, `iscapitalize()` should be `capitalize()`, and that second `for` loop seems useless (whether it is inside the first loop or after it, which is not clear from the question's indentation).

This should work:

```
for word in sentence.split():
    first_letter = word[0]
    if first_letter in consonants:
        pig = word[1:] + first_letter + "ay"
    else:
        pig = word + "ay"
    if word.istitle():
        print(pig.capitalize())
    else:
        print(pig)
```

Or shorter, using ternary `... if ... else ...` statements:

```
for word in sentence.split():
    pig = (word[1:] + word[0] if word[0] in consonants else word) + "ay"
    print(pig.capitalize() if word.istitle() else pig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed solution that cleans up your code and makes it more efficient. See comments in code.

```
sentence = input ("Type in your sentence here ")

#Use "not a vowel" instead of "is a consonant". 
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'] 

#Iterating through words of sentence
for word in sentence.split():
    first_letter = word[0]

    #Now you don't have to type out all the consonants
    if first_letter not in vowels:
        pig = word [1:] + first_letter + "ay"
    else:
        pig = word + "ay"
    #No need for second loop, you're already iterating through each word in the sentence. 
    #end=" " prints out a sentence instead of individual lines. 
    if not pig.islower():
        pig = pig.title()
    print(pig, end=" ")
```

Resources:

[Title case](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_title.htm)

[islower()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_islower.htm)

Comment: With the (useless) second loop you also removed the restoring-title-case part.

Comment: Forgot to copy that line in. Edited with a fix. Now if the word has uppercase characters, it will print it as title case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I have tested the code, but the result is still the same, and having consonants still messed it up (Test --> Testay instead of Esttay)

Comment: Treats uppercase *vowels* as *consonants*.  I.e. `Animal` goes to `Nimalaay` instead of 'Animalay`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few problems I solved:

- There was no need of Second loop as mentioned in other answers.
- Also you need to add capital consonants as well
- islower() == True as True is a boolean and islower() returns boolean. Also if will work if islower() returns True so I just wrote islower()
- Also try to understand that islower() does not see the first letter but just returns True if any of the letter is capital.

```html
sentence = input ("Type in your sentence here ")

consonants2 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# comment the below 3 lines if you don't need to change format for words which starts with capital consonant letter. I 
# I added it because of your example Testay and Esstay which somehow suggest me that you want that.
for i in consonants2:
    consonants.append(i.capitalize())


for word in sentence.split():
    first_letter = word[0]

    if first_letter in consonants :
        pig = word [1:] + first_letter + "ay"
    else :
        pig = word + "ay"
    if pig[0].islower():
        print(pig.capitalize())
    else:
        print(pig)
```

Comment: When I run this, it dumps the consonants to the output and then prints ***all** the pig latin words capitalized!

Comment: @cdlane Oh! I actually forgot to comment that print statement I used to just checkout things. I edited it now. Also I edited the question. What my code does it is it applies "ay" to every word but if the word starts with consonant lowercase or Upercase it sends that at the back before "ay". Finally it capitalize the word.

Answer (score 0):

A variant on the many solutions offered that tries to both be (actually) efficient and produce correct, and correctly formatted, output:

```
sentence = input("Type in your sentence here: ")

vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')

for word in sentence.split():
    first_letter = word[0]

    if first_letter in vowels:
        latin = word + "ay"
    else:
        latin = word[1:] + first_letter + "ay"

    print(latin if latin.islower() else latin.capitalize(), end=' ')  # fix case: Skip -> kipSay -> Kipsay

print()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Type in your sentence here: Horton hears a Who
Ortonhay earshay aay Howay 
>
```