# Maintaining first-letter capitalization in Python pig latin translator

Tags: python

I have a pig latin translator program (yes, I've searched and reviewed several posts) but cannot figure out one part regarding applying capitalization.

My thinking is once I have the final 'pigged word', if the first letter of the original input was uppercase, do the same for the translated/pigged word using the `title()` or `capitalize()` function (like [Pig_Latin Captitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704394/pig-latin-captitalization/56704629#56704629)).

I'm sure this overall solution could be improved but I'm really only seeking guidance on the capitalization piece. (Though all constructive criticism is always welcome!)

```
    # If first letter was capitalized, maintain that in 'pigged' word
    # Example: "Shark" to "Arkshay"
    # Convert any other caps to lower
    # Example: "ShaRK" still to "Arkshay"
    if not first_one.islower():
        pigged_input = pigged_input.title()
    return pigged_input
```

That snippet is contained in the full code:

```
def pig_latin_translator(user_input):
    """ Translator function """
    vowels = "aieou"
    special_two = ("qu")
    first_one = user_input[0]
    first_two = user_input[0:2]
    pigged_input = ''

    # Input begins with vowel: keep input and add "yay"
    if first_one in vowels: 
        pigged_input = user_input.lower()
        pigged_input += "yay"
        return pigged_input
    else: 
        pigged_input = user_input.lower()

        # Input does not begin with vowel: find position of first vowel
        for letter in user_input:
            if letter in vowels:
                index_value = user_input.index(letter)
                break

        # Special two-letter cases: move both letters to end and add "ay"
        # Example: "quarter" to "arterquay"
        if first_two in special_two:
            pigged_input = user_input[2:] + user_input[:2] + "ay"
            return pigged_input

        # Regular pig latin: move indexed letter to end and add "ay"
        else:
            pigged_input = user_input[index_value:] + user_input[:index_value] + "ay" 
            return pigged_input

    # If first letter was capitalized, maintain that in 'pigged' word
    # Example: "Shark" to "Arkshay"
    # Convert any other caps to lower
    # Example: "ShaRK" still to "Arkshay"
    if not first_one.islower():
        pigged_input = pigged_input.title()
    return pigged_input



def error_check_and_print(x):
    """ Error checking function
        If zero-length or contains non-alpha characters, print error message
        Otherwise print result from translator function
    """
    if len(x) == 0:
        print("Error: Not anything!")
    elif not x.isalpha():
        print("Error: Not alpha only!")   
    else:
        return print(pig_latin_translator(x))

pigged_Shark = error_check_and_print("Shark")
# returns "arkShay" but want "Arkshay"
```

Comment: What is your exact problem with using [`str.capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)?

Comment: It is not applying the capitalization and I don't see why.

Comment: You return the arkShay  before captalized ...Please return after captialized

Comment: Ah, so only return when all is said and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the word **arkShay** before captalized ...Please return pigged_input only at function end.

I have modified your code

```
def pig_latin_translator(user_input):
    """ Translator function """
    vowels = "aieou"
    special_two = ("qu")
    first_one = user_input[0]
    first_two = user_input[0:2]
    pigged_input = ''

    # Input begins with vowel: keep input and add "yay"
    if first_one in vowels: 
        pigged_input = user_input.lower()
        pigged_input += "yay"
    else: 
        pigged_input = user_input.lower()

        # Input does not begin with vowel: find position of first vowel
        for letter in user_input:
            if letter in vowels:
                index_value = user_input.index(letter)
                break

        # Special two-letter cases: move both letters to end and add "ay"
        # Example: "quarter" to "arterquay"
        if first_two in special_two:
            pigged_input = user_input[2:] + user_input[:2] + "ay"
            # return pigged_input

        # Regular pig latin: move indexed letter to end and add "ay"
        else:
            pigged_input = user_input[index_value:] + user_input[:index_value] + "ay" 
            # return pigged_input

    # If first letter was capitalized, maintain that in 'pigged' word
    # Example: "Shark" to "Arkshay"
    # Convert any other caps to lower
    # Example: "ShaRK" still to "Arkshay"
    if not first_one.islower():
       pigged_input = pigged_input.title()
    return pigged_input



def error_check_and_print(x):
    """ Error checking function
        If zero-length or contains non-alpha characters, print error message
        Otherwise print result from translator function
    """
    if len(x) == 0:
        print("Error: Not anything!")
    elif not x.isalpha():
        print("Error: Not alpha only!")   
    else:
        return print(pig_latin_translator(x))

pigged_Shark = error_check_and_print("Shark")
```